# Core Plot - Custom Image for Grid Line

Tags: core-plot

Is it possible to have a custom image as grid line for axis in core plot ?

I want to set a 2 pixel height custom image for my requirement.

Setting color for grid line using the image as pattern doesnt produce the effect as like image.

- Balaji R.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a `lineFill` property that is part of the line style. You can create a fill with the image. I'm guessing you'll also want to set the `tiled` property of the image to `YES`.

The `lineFill` property was added after the 1.0 release, so until after the next release you'll need to pull the latest code using Mercurial to get this feature.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for the information. I took the source using mercurian.May i know when is the next release available ? Any tentative date ?

Comment: Core Plot doesn't have a regular release schedule. It's probably near the next point release, but no specific date yet.